# Finding the maximum without using calculus

Tags: contest-math

Find integers $x, y, z > 0$ where:

$xy - xz - 10z$ is maximal, and $2x + y + z = 110$

How would one solve something like this using just algebra? It would be trivial to solve with calculus, but that shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: In general, finding max/min with integrality conditions is a matter of searching near the max min absent those conditions. Here,  absent positivity and integrality you'd want $\{27.5,55,0\}$, for which your function gives $1512.5$.  So I would search near there.  At $\{27,55,1\}$ you get $1448$ which looks like a strong candidate (but I didn't look very hard).

Answer (score 3):

$z = 0$ seems obvious. (or smaller is better).
Since $z$ is strictly greater than $0.$ Set $z = 1$

That makes it 
maximize $xy$
constrained by $2x+y = 109$

$y = 109 - 2x\\
109x - 2x^2$

$ax^2 + bx + c$ is (with $a<0$) is maximized when $x = -b/2a$ (vertex of a parabola)
$x = 110/4$

the non-integer solution is
$(27.25, 54.5, 1)$

The maximal integer solution will be

$(27, 55, 1)$

Comment: $xy - xz - 10z = 27*56=1512$ .  I can get higher by letting $y = -160$ $x=-10$ and $z = 290$ then $2x + y + z = -20 - 160 + 290 = 110$ and $xy - xz - 10z = 1600 + 2900 - 2900 = 1600$.

Comment: @fleablood  you missed a constraint  x,y,z >0.  Otherwise it is unbounded.

Comment: You forgot $z>0$ too.

Comment: oops......  But you missed $z > 0$.

Comment: you are right, I wanted it to be $z\ge 0$!

Comment: This is good.  But I just don't like the "x = 0 is obvious".   I had to convince myself by writing xy - xz - 10z = xy -z(10 + x)$ and if x decreased while x and/or y increase then result increases so max occurs when z is minimal.  ... I don't know, maybe that's the same as  "x =0 is obvious".

Comment: $-xz<0, -10z<0$  if $(x > -10), xy - xz - 10 z$ decreases as $z$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

@Doug M @fleablood

First of all, due to the constraint:

$$\tag{0}2x+y+z=110,$$

we have the following range of *integer* values: $1 \leq x \leq 54$, $1 \leq y,z \leq 106$.

Taking into account (0), one can factor this expression into:

$$xy - (x+10)z = 2(x^2 + x y  - 45 x + 5 y - 550 )=2(x + 5)(x + y - 50) - 600.$$

It is clear that this maximization is equivalent to the maximization of

$$\tag{1}P=(x + 5)(x + y - 50)$$

Let us give a fixed value to $z$.

$P$ is a product of factors whose sum ($2x+y-45$) is a constant equal to $155-z$ (using (0)).

It is well known in such a case that the maximum occurs if the two factors are equal, i.e., if

$$x+5=x+y-50 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ y=55.$$

Remark: this value of $y$, due to constraint (0), has the consequence that $x \leq 27.$

Plugging this value of $y$ into (1), one gets:

$P=(x+5)^2$ which is maximized for the largest possible value of $x$ i.e., $x=27$.

Thus, due to (1), $z=110-2x-y=1$ ; the final solution is then:

> $$(x,y,z)=(27,55,1).$$